# Simple Vue store pattern - initial server fetch not reacting

Tags: vue.js

This app isn't complicated. I'm trying to create a simple store (not keen to use Vuex for something this light) which should coordinate server requests and make sure there's a single source of truth across the app.

**store.js**

```js
import Vue from "vue"
import axios from "axios"

class Store {
  items = []

  constructor() {
    this.fetchData()
  }

  fetchData() {
    axios
      .get("/api/items")
      .then(response => this.fillFieldsFromServer(response.data))
  }

  fillFieldsFromServer(data) {
    // NONE OF THESE WORK

    // 1: this.items = data
    // 2: this.items = this.items.concat(data)
    // 3: Array.prototype.push.apply(this.items, data)
  }
}

export const itemStore = Vue.observable(new Store())
```

**component.vue**

```
<template>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="item in items">{{ item }}</li>
  </ul>
</template>

<script>
  import { itemStore } from "../../stores/item-store.js"

  export default {
    computed: {
      items() {
        return itemStore.items
      },
    },
  }
</script>
```

Obviously I'm fundamentally misunderstanding something here.

What I thought would happen:

1. The store singleton is created
2. A server request is fired off
3. Vue makes the store singleton reactive
4. The component renders with an empty list
5. The component watches `store.items`
6. The server request returns
7. The store updates `items`
8. The component sees that changes
9. The component re-renders with the server data

But what's actually happening is that step (8) doesn't occur. The server request returns fine, but the component doesn't see the change so it doesn't re-render.

Obviously I'm doing something wrong. But what?

Comment: What happens if you define `items` in the constructor (using `this`)?  `this.items = []`

Comment: This is working: https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-pare-7rxby

Comment: Thanks @Dan, good thought, but no particular success there.

Comment: Sorry, but what's the issues with Vuex? You want a single source of truth? Vuex is not heavy or complex to set up at all. If you're just trying to learn the inner workings of state management, great, but avoiding using/learning Vuex and recreating the wheel seems like a waste.

Comment: Thanks @AhmetZeybek, that does seem to work. And then even if I change your code so it's exactly the same as mine (you had the fetch being triggered in `mounted`), I can't reproduce the problem on codesandbox.io. That suggests maybe there's some problem with latency or similar when I'm running it on my dev machine.

Comment: @Arc: Very fair point, I'll give it a quick test and see if that changes anything.

Comment: @DaveSlutzkin you don't have to fetch in `mounted`, same result will be given in `constructor`

Comment: @AhmetZeybek Yes, but unfortunately I can't reproduce the problem I was having even when fetching in the constructor, when the code runs on codesandbox.io. Which I guess means there's something wrong when I run it locally.

Comment: @Arc Looks like it still recurs even using Vuex.

Comment: @DaveSlutzkin Post the new code from the component and Vuex and I can help you out with it.

Answer (score 0):

`Vue.observable` makes an object reactive by recursively replacing existing properties with `get`/`set` accessors, this allows to detect when they are changed. As for arrays, `Array.prototype` methods that mutate existing array are also replaced to track their calls.

This isn't supposed to work because `Array.prototype.push.apply !== store.items.push`:

```
Array.prototype.push.apply(this.items, data)
```

It should be either:

```
  fillFieldsFromServer(data) {
    this.items = data;
  }
```

Or:

```
  fillFieldsFromServer(data) {
    this.items.push(...data);
  }
```

Here is a [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-feather-v30vi).

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. But in my situation none of those options are working either. It's clearly not the code so much as my dev setup.